# TNetHTTPClient and Firebase Storage in Delphi Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, firebase-storage

i am working with firebase and want to upload an image to storage by using TNetHTTPClient. The code in the following does not work. i really appreciate if 
somebody help.

```
procedure test;
 var st:TStringStream;
     bmp : TBitmap;
     msg:string;
 begin
  try
    st:=TStringStream.Create;
    bmp:=TBitmap.Create;
    bmp.LoadFromFile('C:\Users\sammikael\Downloads\test.jpg');
    bmp.SaveToStream(st);
    NetHTTPClient1.ContentType:='image/jpeg';
    NetHTTPClient1.Post('https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/popbom-52bda.appspot.com/o?uploadType=media&name=userprofile',st).ContentAsString();
    showmessage(msg);
  finally
    bmp.DisposeOf;
    st.Free;
 end;
end;
```

thanks

Comment: from the docs **To send the content of a local file, specify the local path to that file as the second argument of your call.** Try that instead of using a stream.. also, are you getting an error message? If so, what is it?

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime a new open source library is available on *GitHub* for *Firebase Storage* and *Firebase Functions* as well as for the *Firebase Realtime Database* and the new *Firestore Database*:

Get more information on https://github.com/SchneiderInfosystems/FB4D

Answer (score 0):

I did this, you need to grant privileges on your firebase Storage.

```
procedure TFHome.pSubeImagen();
var
     vlfile_storage,
     vlfile_download,
     msg:string;
     OpenDialog1 : TOpenDialog;
     JRespuesta: TJSON;
 begin
        TThread.Queue(TThread.CurrentThread,
          procedure
          begin
            vlfile_storage         := 'users_pics/'+vglocalId+'.png';
                    vlfile_download        := 'https://storage.cloud.google.com/'+
                                              FBaseSTORAGE +'/'+
                                              vlfile_storage  ;
                    if vlFileFoto <> '' then begin
                          cgNetHTTPClient_Img.ContentType:='image/jpeg';
                          msg:= cgNetHTTPClient_Img.Post('https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/'  +
                                                          FBaseSTORAGE +
                                                          '/o?uploadType=media&name='+
                                                          vlfile_storage+
                                                          '&key='+WEB_API_KEY,vlFileFoto).ContentAsString();
                          msg := msg.Replace(Char(#10), '');
                          if msg.Contains('mediaLink') then  begin
                              JRespuesta      := TJSON.parse(msg);
                              vlfile_download := JRespuesta.Items['mediaLink'].Value;
                              pCargaImagen(vlfile_download)
                          end
                          else
                              showmessage(msg);


                    end;
          end);


end;
```